# Cube mesh is not drawing in the specified div

Tags: javascript, css, html, three.js

I drew a Torus and Cube Mesh in my scene, and i want the cube to be positioned in the bottom right corner of the screen, so i did like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right:0px; width: 100px; text-align: center; ">
     <script>
         var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(50,50,50),
         new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000}));
         scene.add(cube);   
     </script>
</div>
```

However, the cube is still following the center of the screen: http://medigarage.com/html5/js/three.js/examples/canvas_camera2.html

Am i missing something? Thanx in advance.

EDIT:

I tried to make new renderer, scene and camera for the cube like this:

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="share">
```

**CSS code:**

```
#share  {

             border: 1px solid black; /* or none; */
             margin: 20px;
             padding: 0px;
             width: 200px;
             height: 200px;
             position: absolute;
             right: 0px;
             bottom: 0px;

             }
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script>
        //dom
        var container2=document.getElementById('share');
        //renderer
        var renderer2 = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer2.setSize(200,200);
        container2.appendChild(renderer2.domElement);
        //Scene
        var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
        //Camera
        var camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50,200/200,1,1000);
        camera2.up=camera.up;
        scene2.add(camera2);
        //Axes
        var axes2= new THREE.AxisHelper();
        scene2.add(axes2);
        //Add Cube
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(50,50,50),
               new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000}));
        scene2.add(cube);
        //

        renderer2.render(scene2,camera2);

        </script>
```

I got the div in the right place, but the cube is not there, in the web console everything is ok, i got no error regarding this. Could you point me to the missing point?
You still can see it on live here: http://medigarage.com/html5/js/three.js/examples/canvas_camera2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want by following this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CYMtV/

Also see the related thread: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1372

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, actually i followed the first link your suggest and i adapted my code but the cube is not placed in the right `div`, please see my updated post.

Comment: You need to set `camera2.position.z = 100;` and add the following to the bottom of your `render()` function: `cube.rotation.y += 0.01; renderer2.render(scene2, camera2);`

Comment: Oh, sorry, i forgot about it, thanx a lot :)